# Downloading multiple images with Phonegap - FileTransfer

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, cordova, file-transfer

I have built an offline app in Phonegap, the JSON data gets pushed and gets to where it needs to go. But there are always a bunch of images that need to follow, and html5 cache will just not do it seeing it clears when an app is closed. I have been breaking my nugget on this for quite a while now.

The issue is that you want to check if the image exists on the file system. I've chosen to do so with a "async:false" AJAX call, and therefore have the code running up to a point. I haven't used the phonegap (almost hack) way by writing and setting overwrite to false (which produces an error) seeing that was another async function I didn't want to deal with (wherein lies the problem: async).

Another problem is that the Phonegap browser allows best for 3 downloads at the time (looked it up). My previous function was suffering from this debacle as it would just cut off downloading images if the amount simultaneous downloads was to high, which was around 20 to 40 (depending on size) images at the time (which of course is not strange seeing download speed plummets when you divide it over multiple downloads at the time).

So the question is, how to build:

1. A function that loops through JSON data (image variables).
2. Downloads them three at the time (and set the meta data because Apple told it had to)
3. Deletes from disk those who are not needed anymore (this last one is problem all over the inet as far as I've read, so we'll keep this optional and because by now I really don't actually care about space anymore).
4. Should run a function when all images are downloaded.

My code as far:

```
var datadir = "";
var pics_at_the_time = 0;
var external_url_pics = "http://Folder on server where images are";

// new_config.pics holds the JSON data. Built: '[ key (same as id) { "id": 1234567890, "tld":"jpg" }'. id+'.'+tld = the image name. 

window.requestFileSystem( // get the root folder path
    LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT,
    0,
    function(fileSystem) {
        datadir = fileSystem.root.fullPath;
    },
    function() {
        console.log("Could not get root FS");
    }
);

function fetch_images() {
    var len = new_config.pics.length; // amount of pictures that need to be here
    var all_in_counter = 0;
    $.each(new_config.pics,function(index,val){ // loop through all pics
        pic_exists(val);
    });
}

function pic_exists(val) {
    $.ajax({ // pic on disk or not
        async:false,
      url: 'file://'+datadir+'/'+val.id+'.'+val.tld, //or your url
      success: function(){
        var obj = val.id;
        delete new_config.pics.obj;
      },
      error: function(){
        var obj = val.id;
        delete new_config.pics.obj;
        downloadImage(val);
      }
    });
}

function downloadImage(val){
    if(pics_at_the_time < 3) { // only 3 at a time. else wait for a download to finish
        pics_at_the_time++;
        var ft = new FileTransfer();
        ft.download(
        external_url_pics+val.id+'.'+val.tld,
        datadir + "/" + val.id+'.'+val.tld,
        function(entry) {
            if(debug_console) { console.log("download complete: " + entry.name); }
            entry.setMetadata(function(metadata) { } , function(error) { console.log("Could not set meta data: "+val.id); }, { "com.apple.MobileBackup": 1}); // no apple cloudbackup for these pics. We can always re-download apparently
            pics_at_the_time--;
            fetch_images();
        },
        function(error) {
        if(debug_console) { console.log("download error target " + error.target); }
        pics_at_the_time--;
        fetch_images();
        });
    }
}
```

As you can probably tell, the code is not very sophisticated and it definitely does not check for already existing images. Cause although this works, it is far from perfect seeing it reloops the bunch every time, which at first seemed like a good idea. But now I'm having second thoughts.

Any help is obviously appreciated